# Angular js directive not working in for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a diective in ng-repeat which when i click i pass date and time to the function    showAppointmentForm but here the problem is when I click on first index of loop i get date and time displayed in modal box but when I click on second ,third and so on its values are coming as function parameters but not displayed.Is this something problem with using directives in for loop.Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Using directive in template,

```
 <div data-ng-repeat="doctor in doctors">  
  <appointment-timings data-ng-if="appointments" appointments="appointments" physician="doctor.npi"  width="2"></appointment-timings>

 </div>
```

My appointmnt directive,

```
  $scope.showAppointmentForm = function(date,time) {
    $scope.appointmentData = {};
    $scope.appointmentData.physician = $scope.physician;
    $scope.appointmentData.date = '';
    $scope.appointmentData.time = '';
    $scope.appointmentData.date = date.toString();
    $scope.appointmentData.time = time;
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.$apply();
      $('#appointments').modal('show');
    },500);
  }
```

My Directive html,(A modal box)

```
<div class="date-time">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><b>DATE</b></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="appointmentData.date" disabled>
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><b>TIME</b></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="appointmentData.time" disabled>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="scheduled-hours" id="scheduled-scroll">
<ul>
  <li data-ng-click="showAppointmentForm(date, time)" data-ng-repeat="time in times">{{time}}</li>
</ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: Could you please make a plnkr

Comment: I couldn't see a call of `showAppointmentForm`

Comment: @Dmitry,I edited my code.

Comment: What is the `date` object? Perhaps it is `undefined`. If so, the `showAppointmentForm` function will fail on `date.toString()`, and AngularJS just silently falls

Comment: I am getting problem with time.